# Error when I try to subset my dataframe based on values in column of another dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 4199 values. It looks like this:

`df1$factor <– c("fgsgh:fshg:f92-w", "fqweir:pqfy:2009-fg(877)", "gdhgka:2794:f8v")`

This column of values matches exactly 4199 cells in a column in a dataframe with 71 columns and about 150,000 rows:

`df2$alt_factor  <– c("fgsgh:fshg:f92-w", "fqweir:pqfy:2009-fg(877)", "gdhgka:2794:f8v", "xrxw75:7d5c:e(s)djg7")`

I am trying to subset all of the columns in df2 so that I get all of the values in the 72 columns but only the 4199 rows that match `df1$factor` using this code:

`test <- df2[trimws(df1$factor) %in% trimws(df2$alt_factor), ]`

However, every time I get the same error code:

`Error in [.data.table... : 
  i evaluates to a logical vector length 4199 but there are 144415 rows. Recycling of logical i is no longer allowed as it hides more bugs than is worth the rare convenience. Explicitly use rep(...,length=.N) if you really need to recycle.`

Any ideas how to overcome this problem? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please consider to provide a small  reproducible example.  From the error, it looks like you need `df2[trimws(factor) %chin% trimws(df1$alt_factor)]`

Comment: Do you mean desired output or do you want to see more of the second dataframe?

Comment: Based on the error, I guess you have a data.table and you are tryiing to do the comparison from the second table, instead it would be reverse.  Please see my updated comment

Comment: Please check my solution.  I am able to reproduce your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison should be in the reverse because the logical `%in%` evaluates to the lhs and gives the length based on that which the original data doesn't have that many rows or may be more than that.

```
library(data.table)
df2[trimws(alt_factor) %chin% trimws(df1$factor)]
#       alt_factor
#1:          a
#2:          b
#3:          c
#4:          a
```

---

OP's error is reproducible with the simple example

```
df2[trimws(df1$factor) %in% trimws(df2$alt_factor), ]
```

> Error in `[.data.table`(df2, trimws(df1$factor) %in%
>   trimws(df2$alt_factor),  : 
>         i evaluates to a logical vector length 4 but there are 6 rows. Recycling of logical i is no longer allowed as it hides more bugs than
>   is worth the rare convenience. Explicitly use rep(...,length=.N) if
>   you really need to recycle.

Now, lets check what is happening

```
df2[, trimws(df1$factor) %in% trimws(df2$alt_factor)]
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

It returns a logical vector of length 4 and the number of rows in 'df2' is 6, thus creating imbalance for indexing the rows of the dataset.  Instead, if we do the opposite

```
df2[, trimws(alt_factor) %chin% trimws(df1$factor)]
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

the logical vector is of the same length as the number of rows of 'df2'

#### data

```
df1 <- data.table(factor  = factor(c(' a', 'b', 'a', 'c ')))
df2 <- data.table(alt_factor = factor(c(' a', 'b', 'c', 'd ', 'e', 'a')))
```